# How to have multiple cases inside PaintEvent - using Timer

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, invalidation, paintevent

I'd like to use multiple cases inside PaintEvent, switched using Timer:

```cs
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    switch (scene)
    {
        case 1:
            foreach (Tunnels boxes in tunnellist)//draws series of boxes, creating "tunneleffect" by looping using Invalidate();
            {
                boxes.Draw(e.Graphics);
                Invalidate();
            }
            break;

        case 2:
            foreach (....//here I would like to have some other effect, for example drawing list of sprites moving using sine-waves etc.
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

and in Timer I have following (ticking every 20 seconds):

```cs
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (scene > 1)
    {
        scene = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        scene++;
    }
    this.Invalidate();
}
```

The problem here is that as I have the Invalidate() in PaintEvent, the timer never fires. Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: sounds like calling `Invalidate` inside OnPaint causes a infinite loop, i.e. do not do that! If you need help on how to draw the "tunnel effect" without that you need to describe what effect you are after.

Comment: To expand on the previous comment: it's not at all clear in your post why you even call `Invalidate()` in the `OnPaint()`. So, while it's clearly the wrong thing to do (per both your observation as well as that in the previous comment), it's not at all clear how one would formulate a proper _answer_ to this question addressing whatever it is you're actually trying to accomplish here.

Comment: Well in Form1_Load I create a list of variables for 20 rectangles from small to big which I draw with Draw() method (Tunnels class) using DrawEllipse. The coordinates include: x, y, width, height, "speed" (the multiplier which increases the the size) and r,g,b values (ie. ones being bigger and "closer" have whiter color).  And when looping these it creates a sensation of moving tunnel etc. To put it simple: I 'd like to create old school looping demoeffects - being an old school guy :-)

Comment: I think I should have formulated my question, in a nutshell: how to have different graphics effects (moving sprites, looping starfield etc.) running for some time (for example 20 secs) and then switching to next and so forth

Comment: Invalidate will trigger the Paint event again and freeze the UI, preventing the Timer from doing anything else. - Also: Do note that the Paint event is always expected to __each time draw everything__ that is supposed to show on the control. If you let it draw sometimes this and sometimes that then that and this will go away sometimes and sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

[Control.Invalidate:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate?view=net-5.0)

> Invalidates a specific region of the control and causes a paint message to be sent to the control.

Why would you want to send a paint message inside the paint event handler? Why not just start painting?

It depends a bit of which Control you are paining. Are the boxes that you draw in the same Control? Then it will be sufficient to draw the boxes. No need to invalidate again.

If you want to draw the boxes in a different control than the Control that you are painting right now, you should not invalidate this Control, but the Control in which the Boxes must be drawn. This will lead to an Onpaint for that Control. Use that event to paint the Boxes without Invalidate.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that if I dont't Invalidate() in paint event I end up having static picture of the boxes forming the tunnel, ie. no animation.
I'm painting straight to Form canvas (=control).

I tried to make a workaround having two timers, one ticking every 20 secs (changing scenes) and other every 20 millisec (Invalidating). However, this resulted in jerky motion.